# Is built-in pojo supports of Jersey implemented using jackson?

Tags: java, json, jersey, jackson, jax-rs

I am following some tutorials on the internet. I am doing certain poc and what I have observed that there is not any difference in output while using Jersey built in POJO support or enabling Jackson json serializer. 
I used following code snippet for enabling jersey buit-in support for json

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

For enabling jackson using Jersey:

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
  <param-value>com.foo.com,org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Answer (score 0):

For easiest use of Jersey with Jackson, I would recommend using [DropWizard](https://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/): it runs latest Jackson with Jersey.